# Memory Leak on enum class

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat6, memory-leaks

We have a constants class which has a list of jsps/servlets in an enum class. This class is used from controller servlet to act as redirect. This particular class is always shown in memory analyzer as leak suspect.

I am pasting the code from controller servlet here:

```
 protected void forwardPage(Page jspPage, boolean checkTrail, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
 String temp;
 String str = new String();

 str = jspPage.name();

Page page1 =  Page.valueOf(Page.class,str);
    try {
        temp = page1.getFileName();
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(temp).forward(request, response);  
    } catch (Exception se) {
    } finally { 
        page1 = null;
        jspPage = null;
        str = null;
        temp = null;
    }
```

Page itself is an enum class with a code like this..

UPDATE_PROFILE_CONFIRM("/WEB-INF/jsp/login/updateProfileConfirm.jsp", "Confirm your profile")
public String getTitle() {

```
    return this.title;
}


public String getFileName() {
    return this.fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String newFileName) {
    this.fileName = newFileName;
}
```

What I am not able to understand is why this class should leak? Once I remove the reference of Page and directly redirect, the issue seems to go away. There are no frameworks, simple servlet-jsp framework. Application server is Tomcat 6 and on JDK 6.

Comment: Why do you initialize `String str` with `new String()`?  Why not make it `String pageName = jspPage.name();` Or for that matter, why pull it out as a variable at all? `jspPage.name()` is perfectly good self-documentation.

Comment: Ok.. thats true, but I dont think that in itself can cause any leak.

Comment: "This particular class is always shown in memory analyzer as leak suspect." Are you referring to the Page enum? Does it tell you how many instances are there in the heap?

Comment: and, why do you take a Page as parameter, and change it to string and convert it back to Page again? There is meaningless doing that.

Comment: @SimoneGianni yes, its complaining about Page Enum it tells me that there are total instances of 301 with each instance size of 44 total size of 13,244

Comment: @AdrianShum I agree.. and I did this to see if the leak goes away, originally, it was not like this.

Comment: Can you post the code of Page? Not necessarily the full list of values. If it's an enum, you cannot call "new" on it, so 301 instances should be the 301 values declared there, no matter how many times you convert it to something else.

Comment: Is this leak in production or development? If development, are you changing the JSP and reloading the page? Is the Page type used any place else?

Comment: @SimoneGianni there seems to be 301 declarations inside the enum, these are some other constructors and methods in the class

Comment: We are not deploying any jsps right now, the issue seems to be there from some time now. Page iself is used in many servlets, but all the servlets extend this controller servlet and the method I posted forwardPage is used in them.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that since the enum has 301 values, there are 301 instances of that enum always in ram, and this is normal, cause these instances are statically linked to the enum class. It is not a leak, it is just how enums work.

Memory analyzer is simply telling you that there are 13,244 bytes that cannot be reclaimed, which may be appear as a leak, but it is not. Strange that it does not know about enums, probably simply didn't expect an enum to have 301 values containing a lot of bytes, usually enums have a few elements, storing a limited amount of values, but there's nothing wrong in having an enum like your "Page".

Comment: The thing is, when I do remove this Page reference and use forward directly to the jsp pages from one of the high frequency servlets, the system seems to be behaving well?

Comment: That might be because the enum is not being used anywhere else (?) Then it wouldn't be loaded by the class loader.

Comment: @TonyLâmpada Do you think calling this class as part of initialization would have an impact on that?